# Javascript array length property not being output correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery to populate a header element, passing in a string which is supposed to contain the length of my array:

```
$('#headerText').text('Clue #' + clue + ' of ' + treasureHunt.Clues.$values.length);
```

On running the program, the length property is output as "...". I have no idea why.

However, I can successfully output the length value to the console, e.g.

```
console.log(treasureHunt.Clues.$values.length);
```

So the result value output the console in this case is '5'.

So why doesn't it work as part of the string in the JQuery statement?

I tried wrapping String() around the length property to see if that would cause it to output correctly, but no luck.

Comment: can you do a `console.log('Clue #' + clue + ' of ' + treasureHunt.Clues.$values.length)` and see what is happening

Comment: What css is affecting `#headerText`? do you have a `dotdotdot` plugin installed?

Comment: What is `treasureHunt.Clues.$values`? Does `#headerText` have something like a `text-overflow: ellipsis` style?

Comment: The treasureHunt object is downloaded from the server in XML format, and I use JSON.parse to deserialize (if that's the right word) the data into a Javascript object.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, good idea I just tried that and it output correctly: "Clue #1 of 5".

Comment: @Bergi I'm using JQuery Mobile CSS so I guess that's a possibility. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Bergi you seem to be correct! I modified the string and put "something something" in and reloaded the program, and there is still three dots after "of". I'll try setting text-overflow to none.

Comment: @CiaranG that means either some css properties or some plugin is affecting the text

Comment: In my CSS I tried setting text-overflow to "none" for the header element and used the !important property but I can't seem to override the CSS. Any ideas? (Cheers for the help by the way)

Comment: Check the computed style for the element in firebug/developer tools/... then you can see where the rule is coming from

Comment: Yup found the offending CSS, so I was able to override it. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Credit to @Bergi and @KevinB for pointing me in the right direction with this)

The problem was actually nothing to do with the array, the string was being cut off after a certain amount of characters because of default JQuery Mobile CSS which I've been using in the project, so to solve the problem I had to override the CSS with the following CSS rule:

```
.ui-header, .ui-title, .ui-footer{

    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

It just happened to be the array length property that was being cut out, hence why I missed what the issue actually was!